# Excel Datavalidation list if record satisfies the condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Tasks   | InScope
--------------
T1      |  Yes
T2      |  No 
T3      |  No 
T4      |  Yes
```

I have a table of above type. Now i want to generate a data validation list of Column "Task" if value of "In Scope" is "Yes".

I tried with using index, but it gives me only single value.

```
=INDEX($A1:$A100,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B1:$B100="Yes",0),0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be dynamic then you will need a helper column.

In the first cell put this formula and copy down the length of the full list:

```
=INDEX(H:H,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($I$2:$I$5)/($I$2:$I$5="Yes"),ROW(1:1)))
```

[image]

Then add a named range with the following formula:

```
=Sheet4!$K$2:INDEX(Sheet4!$K:$K,MATCH("zzz",Sheet4!$K:$K))
```

Note: change the sheet and column references to the ones in which your helper column is found.  Make sure the references are absolute.

I called mine `list`

[image]

Then in the cell you want you can use `=list` as the data validation:

[image]

[image]